# Ant formulation transformation from taskdef to exec problem

Tags: java, ant

Due to the same problem than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523042/ant-cant-find-an-ant-class-dateutils-while-building/32630924#32630924)I hava to transform this :

```
    <target name="generateStubs" depends="init">

    <echo message="Generation des stubs depuis project-model"/>
    
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="../src/lib/" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    
    <xjc destdir="${generated.sources.path}">
        <schema  dir="../project-model/src/main/resources/xsd/" includes="*.xsd"/>
        <produces dir="${generated.sources.path}" includes="**/*" />
    </xjc>          
</target>
```

using this kind of formulation :

```
    <exec executable="xjc">
        <arg value="-d"/>
        <arg value="../src/lib/"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
        <arg value="bla.bla.bla"/>
        <arg value="${xjc.in.dir}/bla.xsd"/>
    </exec>
```

I've try some stuff, but I can't figure this out, any idea ?

Comment: what error do you get ? A screen show would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my question was not complete indeed. I don't have the error log anymore but it was a configuration mistake AND an adaptation one : With this use I don't need the -p option. It 's already define in my blabla.xsd.

```
<exec executable="xjc">
        <arg value="-d"/>
        <arg value="${generated.sources.path}"/>
        <arg value="${xjc.xsd.dir}/blabla.xsd"/>
    </exec>
```